# TypeError 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable during heroku deployment

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to deploy my first django app to heroku. I have followed all the settings steps in the guide but I run into the following Traceback during deployment:

```
if 'DATABASES' not in config:
TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable
```

If I disable collectstatic then deployment runs without errors but as soon as I try to migrate my database it raises the same error. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Based on the error message, `if 'DATABASES' not in config():`?

Comment: I was indeed missing parentheses in that I had set config to locals rather than locals(), apologies a beginner's mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was missing a () in my django settings file:

```
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

instead of:

```
django_heroku.settings(locals)
```